# SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

So I am have been trying to connect to  SOAP service that has some very bare minimum documentation literally 1 page.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$wsdl       = "https://example.com/xyzUpload/xyzUpload?wsdl";
$local_cert = "/etc/key/tls/certs/abc123.crt";
$keyfile    = "/etc/key/tls/private/mms.key";
try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('HOSTNAME' => 'example.com','cert_file' => $local_cert,'key_file' => $keyfile,'trace'=>1));
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo "Problem..... : ";
    echo $exception;
}   
?>
```

I get  the following exception

> SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load
> from 'https:...' ...failed to load external entity

so I tried it from python

```
import httplib

CERTFILE = '/etc/key/tls/certs/abc123.crt'
keyfile='/etc/key/tls/private/mms.key'
HOSTNAME = 'example.com'
request_url='https://example.com/xyzUpload/xyzUpload?wsdl'
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(
    HOSTNAME,
    key_file = keyfile,
    cert_file = CERTFILE
)
conn.putrequest('GET',request_url)
conn.endheaders()
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.read()
```

seems to work perfectly.... am I missing something ??

Comment: The PHP SoapClient class works a bit different. Are there any refrences to xsd files in the wsdl file? Is the service location uri the same as the wsdl uri?

Comment: @Marcel the service location uri is same as esdl uri (only difference being ?Wsdl).

Comment: As you 're not sharing the wsdl content, I can not say, what exactly the proplem is. I can only guess and I guess, that the PHP SoapClient class can not load an external entity. Those entities are mostly definitions for wsdl types. Are you referencing to W3C definitions like webservice security (wss or wsc)?

Comment: @Marcel this is what i get just the top snippet i am sharing... <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns:tns="https://example.com/schema/NR_58" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap
/http" name="UploadService" targetNamespace="https://example.com/schema/NR_58"> when i run the python code

Comment: @Marcel and i get this  <wsdl:service name="MCSA58UploadService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:MCSA58UploadServiceSoapBinding" name="MCSA58UploadPort">
      <soap:address location="https://example.com/xyzUpload/xyzUpload"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

Comment: @Marcel i obviously have to change the urls etc as this is a public forum.... but my point the python code works withthe info so why not the SOAP client ....
An example of a complete request header:
{POST https://example.com/xyzUpload/xyzUploadHTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
apikey:  xxxxx
uploadid: xxxWS
Content-Length: 2913
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)}

Comment: Because the PHP SoapClient class is more strict than the Python HTTP client. The thrown exception says, that there couldn 't be retrieved an information from a referenced source in the wsdl. For example: The W3C has a delay on its schemes. If you reference W3C schemes, the PHP SoapClient won 't load them because of the W3C delay while python does. In that case you have to store the W3C definitions locally and refence to the local definition in your wsdl file. Obviously the wsdl you 're trying to use got some problemes with the referenced schemes. It 's not PHP itself. It 's the wsdl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218560/discussion-between-apurva-and-marcel).